# CSS grid - two-column layout (title and description)

Tags: css, css-grid

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.card {
  padding: 1rem;
  height: auto;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 32px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.cardTitle {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardDescription {
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .cardTitle {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .cardDescription {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title one</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description one Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title two</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description two Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title three</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description three Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title four</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description four Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title five </div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description five Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
```

On desktop view it is fine but on smaller views like mobile, I'd like to stack the title and description close together, so the gap between title and description close together but the gap of each row stays the same. Like so:
[image]

What's the best way to achieve this? Is grid the right way to approach this?

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

Only use `display: grid;` on desktop, and then use a `margin-bottom` for controlling the space.

```css
.cards {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-gap: 32px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.cardTitle {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardDescription {
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .cards {
    display: grid;  
  }
  
  .cardTitle {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .cardDescription {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title one</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description one Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title two</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description two Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title three</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description three Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title four</div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description four Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="card cardTitle">Title five </div>
  <div class="card cardDescription">Description five Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
```